# How to move a block from content to custom place

Tags: magento

The block below is added to the bottom of content. I want this block to be called from within the catalog/product/view.phtml. So i can place it with $this->getChildHtml().

```
</PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
<reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom_bundle.phtml" translate="label">
      <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
      <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
      <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone_bundle.phtml"/>
      <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart_bundle.phtml"/>
    </block>
</reference> 
</PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
```

How to do this ? Do I add a new reference ? like :

```
<reference name="content">
  <reference name="blockname">
    <block></block>
  </reference>
</reference>
```